How does one prove that the position of COM of a particle system is independent of position of origin of coordinate system?
Say you have 2 mass particles m1 and m2  about some cartesian coordinate system whose origin is at position A , while another at position B .
How would one prove that the position of COM of the particle system is independent of origin A or B?

Consider the distances between m1, m2, and the COM, in both coordinate frames.

See PM 2Ring comment.

Let's assume that the co-ordinates of the A-frame and B-frame are related by a translation as follows:
$$\vec{r_A} = \vec{r_B} +\vec{a}$$
Then we have to prove that the coordinates of the CoM with respect to the A and the B frames are also related in the same manner.
By definition, in frame A we have
$$\vec{R_A} = \frac{m_1 \vec{r_{1A}}+m_2 \vec{r_{2A}}}{m_1+m_2} =  \frac{m_1 \vec{r_{1B}}+ m_2 \vec{r_{2B}}}{m_1+m_2} +\vec{a} = \vec{R_B} +\vec{a}$$
where in the intermediate step we have used the first equation.

Many thanks and you made it really easy for me to understand.
